# passing parent's state to child's prop and is seen as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build the game Yahtzee.. and I'm facing an issue when trying to pass from parent class **DiceRow** the value of a randomly chosen number to child class **Die**, in function **initDice** within **DiceRow**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Die from './Die';
import './DiceRow.css';
import { rollDie } from './helper';

export default class DiceRow extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dices: [rollDie(), rollDie(), rollDie(), rollDie(), rollDie()],
            isDisabled: [false, false, false, false, false]
        }
        this.handleRoll = this.handleRoll.bind(this);
        this.handleDieClick = this.handleDieClick.bind(this);
        this.initDice = this.initDice.bind(this);

    }

    handleDieClick(id){ // means we need to disable the clicked die

    }

    handleRoll(){
        let new_dices_values = [];

        for(let i=0; i<this.state.dices.length; i++){
            if(!this.state.isDisabled[i]){ // only if is disabled === false
                new_dices_values[i]=rollDie();
            }
            else {
                new_dices_values[i]=this.state.dices[i];
            }
        }
d
        this.setState({
            dices: new_dices_values
        });
        

    }

    initDice(){
        let dices = [];
        for(let i=0; i<this.state.dices.length; i++){
            dices[i] = <Die onClick={this.handleDieClick} value={this.state.dices[{i}]} key={i} id={i}/>
        }
        return dices;
    }

  render() {
    let dices = this.initDice();
    return (
        <div>
      <div className='DiceRow'>
            {dices}
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleRoll} className='DiceRow-RollBtn'>Roll Dice!</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Die.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Die.css';
import {rollDie} from './helper';

export default class Die extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isRolling: false,
            disableRolling: false
        }
    }
  render() {

    let whichDie = <i className={`fa-solid fa-dice-${this.props.value} fa-5x`}></i>
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='Die'>
            {whichDie}
        </div>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[image]

which results in my Dice not to appear ;'(

Thanks in advance, may you all have a day without compilation errors :-D

Comment: Try with ```${this.state.dices[i]}```

Comment: Syntactically it won't work in this form - with the $ sign. I have tried also just doing {this.state.dices[i]} and it didn't work ;[

Comment: But why are you putting the value in the template string?

Comment: Oh man, a moment of lack of focus.. thanks! jeez, was on it for along time.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was the following:

```
initDice(){
        let dices = [];
        for(let i=0; i<this.state.dices.length; i++){
            dices[i] = <Die onClick={this.handleDieClick} value={this.state.dices[{i}]} key={i} id={i}/>
        }
        return dices;
    }
```

let's observe the

> value={this.state.dices[{i}]}

We can notice the JSX curly braces in order for a JavaScript Expression to be interpreted.

If we notice, my issue here was, as stated in the comments by @Abbas Shaikh, I have additionally added { } around the i variable.
That results in the { } brackets, surrounding the i variable, a declaration of an object (JS syntax), and is an object which is not defined properly, hence, the received value is 'undefined'.